# 'Taken' joke on Twitter

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, jokes

I didn't get this joke.

> If I ever put 'Taken' in my Twitter bio, just know it was...
>
> A: By Aliens
>
> B: By the men in white coats
>
> C: Into custody

I know taken is the movie where the daughter gets apprehended  but what are the other two options B and C means in context which makes it funny?

Comment: The joke has nothing to do with the movie. This may be what's confusing you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To continue with what @Roger was saying in his comment, "Taken" in a twitter bio would mean that you are now dating someone – that you are no longer single and not dating. In other words, it means you are in a committed relationship. However, the joke is saying that if this person ever puts "Taken" in their bio, it means something else – that they were physically taken, either by the police (option C), by psychiatrists (option B), or by aliens (option A).

I think we should assume whoever uses this joke has no plans to be in a committed relationship any time soon.

Answer (score 3):

B: if you are taken by men in white coats it is implied that they are doctors (usually psychiatric). This would mean that they have been taken into psychiatric treatment.

C: Taken into custody implies that this person has been arrested by the police and taken 'into custody', under the watch of the police, probably in a cell.